# Por qué los servlet no funcionan en Jelastic

Tags: java

buenas tardes.

Soy principiante en el tema de la programación y estoy creando un proyecto en JAVA utilizando el IDE de Netbeans, el proyecto tiene jsp y servlet, lo que ocurre es que a la hora de desplegar el proyecto en Jelastic es como si no encontrara o funcionaran los servlets, ya que localmente y con Tomcat todo funciona correctamente, pero a la hora de estar desplegado intento registrar un dato y no funciona, sale error 400, y un mensaje diciendo que no encuentra la ruta del servlet que le asigne.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error se produce por la versión de tomcat que utilizas en jelastic. Prueba a cambiarla por la 9 o la 8.